# Remove the package prefix from a custom view in the XML layout

Tags: android, android-custom-view, prefix

I'm using a custom Button View in my app.
Say com.example.myCustomButton.
My XML will look something like this.

```
<com.example.myCustomButton>
   stuff here
<com.example.myCustomButton/>
```

Does anyone know if its possible to setup my custom View in such a way that I can omit the prefix (com.example.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot omit the full path to the non-framework Views.

Without it, the framework doesn't know where to look for those Views and there is no way to register your package with the framework.